# How to generate coverage in a method that throws an Exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

I have a void function that throws an Exception. When I make the unit tests, Sonar doesn't detect coverage and I don't know why.

**My void method:**

```
public void exceptionBadRequest(String errorMessage) throws ClientBadRequestException {
    errorMessage = errorMessage.equals("") ? "Error en su solicitud, request invalido! HTTP 400 Bad Request" : errorMessage;
    throw new ClientBadRequestException(
            errorMessage);
}
```

**Piece of code where I used the method**

```
boolean stateCampaign = (customerCampaign.getStateCampaign().equals(ENCURSO) || customerCampaign.getStateCampaign().equals(RECIBIDO));
    if (!stateCampaign) {
        this.exceptionBadRequest("Esta campaña no se puede gestionar.");
    }
```

**Aaaaaand the test**

```
@Test
void testNoFields() {
    Exception noValidCampaign = assertThrows(ClientBadRequestException.class, () -> documentLabService.saveInformationStatusOffersCampaigns(CustomerCampaign.builder().stateCampaign("PENDIENTE").build(), InformationStatusOffersCampaignsRequestDTO.builder().build()));
    assertEquals("Esta campaña no se puede gestionar.", noValidCampaign.getMessage());
}
```

So, I'm missing something but I don't know what exactly, when I run the test in IntelliJ it tells me it covers it, but when I look the generated report in SonarQube, it appears without coverage.

[image: IntelliJ]

[image: SonarQube]

Answer (score 0):

For a 100% coverage, you need to have a test for the throwing exception case **AND** for the non-exception case like this:

```java
package de.playground.so74230479;

public class ExceptionBadRequest {
    public void exceptionBadRequest(String errorMessage) throws Exception {
        errorMessage = errorMessage.equals("") ? "Error en su solicitud, request invalido! HTTP 400 Bad Request" : errorMessage;
        throw new Exception(
                errorMessage);
    }
    public void myOtherMethod(boolean myBoolean) throws Exception {
        boolean stateCampaign = myBoolean;
        if (!stateCampaign) {
            this.exceptionBadRequest("Esta campaña no se puede gestionar.");
        }
    }
}
```

and the test:

```java
package de.playground.so74230479;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class ExceptionBadRequestTest {
    ExceptionBadRequest ebr = new ExceptionBadRequest();

    @Test
    void testNoFields() {
        Exception noValidCampaign = assertThrows(Exception.class,
                () -> ebr.myOtherMethod(false));
        assertEquals("Esta campaña no se puede gestionar.", noValidCampaign.getMessage());
    }
    @Test
    void testWithFields() {
        try {
            ebr.myOtherMethod(true);
        } catch (Exception e){
            fail("no exception expected");
        }

    }
}
```

[image]